# Soldering a lithium battery to existing PCB terminals

Tags: pcb, soldering, lithium-ion

I've got a PCB with a lithium battery fixed on board.

The PCB has died as the lithium battery has died (for this particular piece of hardware this is a common fault.) See photos below.

I'm trying to buy a replacement battery for the PCB.  I found  the product number online, but it available as a few options (see additional photos below.) The battery is available with solder terminals like Option A and B, but they don't match up to the solder terminals on the PCB.

Should I purchase battery Option C (with no terminals) and try to fix that to the existing solder terminals that are sticking up out of the PCB ? If so what should I use to connect the battery to the existing solder terminals? I've not done this before so any pointers would be much appreciated.

**EXISTING PHOTOS**

[image: side A of battery]

[image: side b of battery]

[image: back of PCB]

[image: Side view of battery]

**BATTERY OPTION PHOTOS**

[image: Battery Option C]

[image: Battery Option B]

[image: Battery Option A]

Comment: Looks like the existing one is option C, and the board just has those two metal contacts that press up against it, right?

Comment: Can you buy a holder with wires and double sides tape? Safest option.

Comment: @Justin:  It looks to me like the tabs on the original are welded to the cell rather than just being a press fit.  A press fit wouldn't hold very well.

Comment: @Justin please see additional photo here : https://imgur.com/a/6i8kXCi - it looks like the battery is fixed in place not just pressed up against the metal terminals

Comment: @Jeroen3 im not sure im following, do you have an example image of something similar ?

Comment: I needed to replace a solder in coin cell once and didn't have one with solder tabs or a spot welder. "What's the worst that can happen?" so I set the soldering iron as hot as possible to minimize heat soaking and just barely wetted the surface and immediately lifted the soldering iron and let it cool off. "See, no worr..." BANG!!! and it exploded in my face. DON'T SOLDER DIRECTLY TO BATTERIES!

Comment: @winny's advice is important. If you really need to attach the terminals to the battery, you may spot-weld. Do not solder.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The correct solution is C, with a holder for the cell soldered to the board.

Do **not** try to solder directly to the ends of the cell.  Most batteries "don't like that."  Lithium cells go further, and will actively protest against being soldered on.  "Protest" as in "burst into flames" - maybe immediately, maybe days or weeks or months later.

Solution A would be my choice if I had to solder the cell on.  That will be tricky, though, since the bare wires would be easy to short out - once again causing "protests" from the cell.

Find a holder made for the cell.  Use a cell without welded on leads. Solder the holder to the board, then put the cell in the holder.

That's safest and simplest all around.  It costs a bit more, but is still much cheaper than having your gadget burst into flames.

---

Your cell is the same size as a standard AA alkaline cell.  A single AA cell holder could be soldered to the existing holes.

[Take your pick from dozens.](https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Keystone-Electronics/2460?qs=3CbvriavsLB6FI3qURcWXQ%3D%3D)

Like this one:

[image]

Put a piece of double sided tape on the bottom side so it will stick to your PCB, then solder it in place and put your cell in.

Comment: To the OP: I would not try to solder directly to the cell either. This contact might work in the existing holes if you are lucky. https://www.keyelco.com/product.cfm/17-19mm-Cell-Battery-Contacts/109-2/product_id/4046

Comment: Thanks @JRE , how would be best to remove the existing dead battery from the existing terminals ?

Comment: Clip the pins with side cutters, then remove the clipped off pieces from the holes, then use a solder sucker to clear the holes.

Comment: I’ve noticed that the original tabs holding the battery connect to the PCB At 1x point on one side, but 3x points on the other side (see image of back side of PCB) how would I connect the battery holder to the 3x points on the PCB ?

Comment: You don't worry about it.  All three holes are connected together on the board.  Just connect one at each end of the cell holder.

Comment: This is what the manufacturer should have done initially, but they "minimised the BOM cost"

Answer (score 4):

Option A looks the easiest to be a drop in replacement if you are comfortable with soldering. Lithium batteries are best kept cool. I know some people do solder to them but I prefer to avoid any risk to my finger.

The tabs on the existing cell should be easy to snip to free the cell. At this point de-solder the remains of the tabs and then clean up using a solder sucker or braid.

The holes you are left with look like they might be a good match to the leads on variant A. Insert the leads of variant A into the holes making sure the polarity matches and solder into place. Soldering like this is likely to introduce less heat into the battery than de-soldering.

As always with lithium batteries, if it starts to get hot, get rid of it (outside ideally) or at least make sure it is on a fire proof surface.

Comment: Thanks , one side of the existing battery tabs has 1x solder point to the PCB, but the other tab connects to 3x solder points on the PCB, how would I get option A to worm with that ?

Comment: @user27511 You can use just one of the three holes in conjuction with securing the battery so it can't move (which would be at least part of the reason for the three holes). A proper holder, as shown in [JRE's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/591735/36731) would be a better option.